# Things to keep in mind while DB update for application migration

Tags: c++, oracle, data-migration

One of my friend has attented C++ Interview and interviewer asked one question on application migration:
"If you are working on migration project which has combination of C++, and Java, and you need to migrate database (lets say from oracle 9i to oracle 10g). then what all the things you will take care  in mind while doing db update or key factor while Database update for your project?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the full answer but one issue are new Privileges which are introduced into new Oracle releases. As far as I remember `EXECUTE ANY CLASS` was introduced in Oracle 10 for example. Those privileges has to be granted in new release, which do not exist in old release.